# Hide child inside parents div and show outside

Tags: css, animation

Is there any way how to hide child inside parent and show after he runned away from div ?? I am using anymation, transform - translate from (100%,0) to (0,0), but during moving, this div overlaps the parent div.. and i cant use z-index because of child. Child cant go upper in layer then parrent... so is there any other way? How to show child only out of parent div ?

[image: relationship]

I am making dynamic menu with anymation, and i want after click on link show subMenu just next to

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: check `overflow` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want something like this ? use `overflow:hidden` on `parent` or if you want the `child` to be visible use `overflow:visible`

you can set `animation` instead. it still works like the example below

let me know if it helps

```css
.parent { 
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:2px solid black;
overflow:hidden;
}
.child {
  width:100px;
  height:96px;
  border:2px solid red;
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.5s;
  
}
.parent:hover .child {
  transform:translateX(30px);
  opacity:1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its little harder, couse i am writting in react js, and i have all time rendered parent div, and only when i click on link in parent div, i am adding to parent child div... so there is no child div all time, its added to dom after click.. so i cant make change of opacity, because there is no div before i clicked..

Comment: could you use the `.fadeIn()` method ? or something similar ? also would help if you shared your code. from your question, my answer will probably be the maximum you will  get